# Best Search-Algorithm to search an Input String

Tags: c, performance, search, input, compare

I have a theoretical question.

I'm trying to find the best search algorithm to deal with the following problem: I want to process a input String, the input String can have up to 7 independent and valid arguments (parameters), which start different segments in my code. All parameters can appear at any position inside the input, which means the input does not have a order.

My first idea was to look at the input string and do a strcmp for all individual valid inputs at every position inside the string, which would mean that I would basically search the string until I find a match or reach the end of the input. However, this would have very bad runtime latency as I would iterate the input with n!.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to search the input, maybe something where I can decrease the sample size after a valid input has been found, so I dont have to look at this position again. I would be glad if someone could help me to find a search-algorithm with a better runtime efficiency.

As far as I know, its not possible to decrease a stack size. I guess the only way to improve the efficiency is to skip positions inside the stack, based on a bool value? Every position that I can skip drastically improves the runtime, as it would have to be compared with all 7 inputs.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm

Comment: Or, simpler to implement, `strcspn()` using the first characters of the N strings to find potential start points and then N `strncmp()`s to see if there's a match at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd bet that your libc implementation does this quite well ;)

strstr() is the function you are looking for, go check this man : http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/strstr.3.html